# Как в Debian освободить порт если fuser -k номер/tcp не помогает?

Tags: linux, tcp, port

Во время разработки сервера, его приходится часто включать/выключать. Естественно порт освобождается не сразу и сервер не стартует из-а 98-й ошибки `EADDRINUSE`. Я не хочу использовать `SO_REUSEADDR` на сокете, просто нужно жёстко закрывать порт и запускать сервер не смотрия ни та что.

`fuser -k номер/tcp` вроде отрабатывает, но ошибка всё равно остаётся какое-то время, в процессах сервер не висит - закрывается корректно.

Как освободить порт в этом случае?

Comment: используйте SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: Что если написать скрипт-обёртку для запуска, который бы ждал, пока порт освободится и потом запускал сервер?

Comment: @NickVolynkin - основная цель тут - побороть время. Тут проц помощнее ищешь чтобы собирало скорее, секунды экономишь, а оно порт занимает на 2 минуты - никуда не годится )

Comment: @Iceman это порт для HTTP или для связи между компонентами сервера? Есть идея, что можно перебирать несколько портов по кругу. Написать обёртку, которая будет перед запуском сервера задавать переменную окружения с портом или передавать его в параметрах/конфигах.

Comment: Это из предположения, что вы не захардкодили номер порта и его можно задать переменной окружения. 12-factor app, вот это всё.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет... я понял уже из-за чего это. Обмен данными происходит по WebSocket. Закрытие соединения WebSocket предусматривает обмен закрывающими фреймами. Я тестировал парсинг фрейма, но не сделал корректную обработку закрытия (не отвечал клиенту должным образом и не вычитывал его closure запрос) - в результате сервер то я закрывал, а на TCP по этому порту висели данные и система не теряла надежды, что их кто-нибудь подберёт )))

Comment: @Iceman вот оно что. Ответ напишете? С меня плюс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и бывает в большинстве подобных случаев, проблема оказалась в другом...

Разрабатываемый сервер осуществляет коммуникацию с клиентами по WebSocket. Закрытие соединения WebSocket предусматривает обмен закрывающими фреймами. Я тестировал парсинг WS-фрейма, но до корректной обработки закрытия руки не дошли (не отвечал клиенту должным образом и не вычитывал его closure запрос) - в результате сервер то закрывался, а на TCP по этому порту висели данные, отправленные клиентом в пустоту - то ли ping, то ли close запрос. Система не теряла надежды, что их кто-нибудь подберёт, и держала порт...

Как только клиент (в данном эксперименте браузер Firefox) стал получать ответ о закрытии, он корректно отключался, а при перезапуске сервера тот стартовал моментально на том же порте без `SO_REUSEADDR`, ошибка 88 более не возникала.

Да, решение не является ответом по изначальной тематике вопроса, но пусть оно служит памяткой для подобный проблем - всегда проверять корректность завершения сеанса связи в разрабатываемых приложениях.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда помогает закрытие сокета извне через `ss -K` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511691/43898 но это в случае если программа не висит в блокировке ввода-вывода.

Comment: Нет, не работает. Программа ведь не может висеть в блокировке, если все потоки, обрабатывающие подключения закрыты, и программа завершена?

Comment: ой как может... вот тоже думаю как бороться с этим

Comment: Заметил, что порт занят когда к серверу выполнялось подключение. Если просто запустить и закрыть, то стартует потом нормально